# Confused by the point of this linear algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

The question reads: 
Let $T : \mathbb{R^4} → \mathbb{R^3}$ be given by $T(v) = Av$, where A = $$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Find the matrix $B$ of $T$ with respect to the basis {$v_1, v_2, u_1, u_2$} of $\mathbb{R^4}$ and the basis {$w_1, w_2, z_1$} of $\mathbb{R^3}$. Verify that $B$ is in canonical form.

Now,

the vectors $u_1, u_2$ are the basis for $ker(T)$ which are $(-1, 1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 1, 0)$.

The vectors $v_1, v_2$ are two vectors which extend the basis of $ker(T)$ to $\mathbb{R^4}$, which I chose to be $(0,0,0,1), (1,0,0,0)$.

The vectors $w_1 = T(v_1) = (2,3,4)$ and $w_2 = T(v_2) = (1,1,0)$, and finally the vector $z_1$ is the vector which extends the basis of {$w_1, w_2$} to $\mathbb{R^3}$, which I chose to be $z_1 = (0,0,1)$.

Can anyone help me put the pieces of the puzzle of this question together for me? I started the question by trying to form the matrix $B$ by applying the transformation to the vectors of the given basis for $\mathbb{R^4}$, but since two of those basis vectors are that of the kernel of T, they just give me back the zero vectors. This is why I'm confused and unsure of the point of the question. Am I missing something here? Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The point of this exercise is to see an example of how the normal form of a matrix can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way. Indeed, the columns of $B$ will be $T(u_1),T(u_2),T(v_1),T(v_2)$, expanded in the basis $\{w_1,w_2,z_1\}$.

Since $T(u_1)=T(u_2)=0$, the first two columns of $B$ will be zero.

Next, $T(v_1)=w_1$, so the third column of $B$ will be $(1,0,0)^T$. Finally, $T(v_2)=w_1$, so the fourth column of $B$ is $(0,1,0)^T$. All in all, we get
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
If you decide that $v_1,v_2$ should be the first two basis vectors of $\Bbb R^4$ instead, then the corresponding two columns of $B$ will move to the left side, giving you
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
It's up to you which one you prefer.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help. Seems the question was way easier than it came across. I was then asked to find non-singular matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $B=Q^{-1}AP$. Is this an extension of the question? Does it have something to do with transition matrices? Sorry if I’m meant to make a new post but was wondering if you had any ideas how to approach it?

Comment: @JamesDebenham $P$ and $Q$ are in this case matrices that translate vectors and linear operations between different bases. I can never remember the right direction (like some people have trouble with left and right, I have trouble here), but either the columns of $P$ and $Q$ are the new basis vectors expressed in the old basis, or they are the old basis vectors expressed in the new one ($P$ is $4\times 4$ and takes care of the translation between the $\Bbb R^4$ bases, while $Q$ is $3\times 3$, taking care of the translation between the $\Bbb R^3$ bases).

Answer (score 0):

I am giving a general result which might help you.

Let $\beta = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \}$ and $\gamma = \{u_1, u_2, u_3 \}$ be the basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively.

Then, define $[T]_\beta^\gamma = \begin{bmatrix}
 | & | & | & | \\
[T(v_1)]_\gamma & [T(v_2)]_\gamma & [T(v_3)]_\gamma & [T(v_4)]_\gamma\\
 | & | & | & | \\
\end{bmatrix}$ as a $3 \times 4$ matrix.

This is the matrix which

1. takes a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with coordinates with respect to the basis $\beta$.
2. applies $T$ to it
3. returns a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with coordinates with respect to the basis $\gamma$.

$[T(v_i)]_\gamma$ is the image of $v_i$ under $T$ with coordinates with respect to the basis $\gamma$, where $v_i \in \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \} = \beta$.