# Confusion about seemingly simple transition matrices question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, transition-matrix

This question is an extension from one of my 
[older questions here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431286/confused-by-the-point-of-this-linear-algebra-question):

Given the matrices A and B, consider transition matrices, and write down non-singular matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $B = Q^{−1}AP$. Check that $QB = AP$.

I know that this question is about relating two bases together, but I've never tried a question like this, and can't find any similar questions online, so need a point in the right direction from anyone! Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by the $1$ in $B = Q−1AP$? Is it the same as $B = Q-AP$?

Comment: @DanielP I have now edited the question to give you the right formula.

Comment: $QB=Q(Q^{-1}AP)=(QQ^{-1})(AP)=1_2AP=AP$

Comment: @Thorgott That's missing the point of the question, so isn't helpful. Sorry